# Retrieving Next Available Entry ID

Tags: ee2, entryid, activerecord

Using Active Record in an EE2 project, is there a specific function that retrieves the next available entry id of a record I am going to insert?

At the moment I have this code to generate the next id before I insert a record into the database:

```
$this->EE->db->select_max('entry_id');
$this->EE->db->from('exp_channel_titles');
$entry_result = $this->EE->db->get()->result_array();
$entry_id = intval($entry_result[0]['entry_id'] + 1);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to find out prior to inserting?

When inserting, you can find out the new entry ID added using...

```
ee()->db->insert_id();
```

From the [Docs](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/helpers.html).

So...

```
$data = array(
           <your field>       =>  <your value>
);
if ( ee()->db->insert('exp_channel_titles', $data) ) {
    $new_entry_id = ee()->db->insert_id();
}
```

I've used the super global here, if you're using an old version of EE, then use the legacy `$this->EE`.

Comment: Certainly looks easy enough!! I knew there must have been something... Thanks!